# Is there any 'Project File' or 'Workspace file' or 'Solution file' equivalent in Yocto Project?

Tags: linux, ide, embedded-linux, development-environment

So, I am using NXP Modular Gateway hardware by Volansys to develop a Software utilizing both Zigbee and Ethernet communication. I was following the Source Build Instruction Guide offered to me with the product and as it turns out, the whole example source code and binary is operating on something called 'Yocto Project' and it uses bitbake which I am not familiar with to build the source codes and make the necessary binaries.

What I am trying to do is, I would like to tweak the source code of the example application NXP and Volansys provided to meet the requirement of my own project. The setback is, even if I have already checked out the whole code and been successful on building them, I have no idea how to analyze the code.

I need to find out where the each variables and functions have been declared and defined and where they are called so that I am able to get the clear idea how the whole processes flows and how to tweak them for my liking. So, here is the question.

Is there anything like Project File or Solution File-as in Visual Studio- equivalent in binaries/source codes working with bitbake/Yocto Projects? If not, what kind of method I could use to analyze source codes so that I can reach my goal -which is tempering the source codes given-? For instance, I thought about using grep to looking for clue from the whole thing, but is it the only way to do this?

I know it sounds strange/silly but I am asking this as a complete beginner with linux environment. Any suggestion/answer provided would be deeply appreciated.

Have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry to say that there is no quick answer to your question. Yocto as a method of distributing Linux is very powerful, and maybe, a good choice for the creators of the distribution, NXP in your case. But it is very complicated to use.

The best way to start with Yocto is to read a book. I like "Embedded Linux Development Using Yocto Project Cookbook - Second Edition" from Packt publishing. If you want a quicker overview, [this](https://www.wolfssl.com/docs/yocto-openembedded-recipe-guide/) and [this](https://training.ti.com/customizing-yocto-for-production-modifying-recipes) site talk about recipes, which is a key concept.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Guess I have to take slower way. *_*